# How to modify a custom field on cart, when the cart is created

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, events, custom-field, cart

I want to set a custom field on shopping cart when I first retrieve it.

https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/extend/events.html#modifycartinfo sounds appropriate so I tried doing this:

```
Event::on(
    BaseFrontEndController::class,
    BaseFrontEndController::EVENT_MODIFY_CART_INFO,
    function(ModifyCartInfoEvent $e) {
        $order = $e->cart;
        $order->setFieldValue('customField', SOME_VALUE);
        $e->cart = $order;
    }
);
```

the event handler is executed, yet `customField` is `null` in the API response.

doing the same thing in an `Adjuster` works. however that only runs on a cart *update* obviously.

---

edit: ok, this explains why it didn't work that way https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/develop/src/events/ModifyCartInfoEvent.php#L28

What's the right way to set the field on carts?

Comment: Hi there, it looks like you may have answered this yourself. Feel free to add the answer to your own question to receive credit and help the community. It is totally valid to answer your own questions here. Thanks!

Comment: the question remains though: how and where do I set the custom field

Comment: Understood, the question has been updated to clarify